# Как в массив вставить новое число которое будет находится между меньшим и большим его числами?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
const arr = [10,15,16,19,23,25,34];
```

Есть число

```
const number = 21;
```

Как вставить это число по возрастанию в массив, т.е. между 19 и 23?
Чтобы массив стал таким:

```
[10,15,16,19,21,23,25,34]
```

Массив всегда возрастающий.

Comment: Добавить с указанием ключа?

Comment: @karashal, просто что бы массив стал таким `[10,15,16,19,21,23,25,34]`

Comment: Как вариант - добавить и отсортировать

Comment: _«добавить и отсортировать»_ - менее эффективно, чем вставка в нужную позицию внутри **уже отсортированного** массива. И чем больше массив, тем ниже эффективность данного подхода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая что

> Массив всегда возрастающий

, можно просто найти индекс первого встреченного элемента со значением больше вставляемого числа - и по этому индексу выполнить вставку:

```js
const arr = [10,15,16,19,23,25,34];
const number = 21;

const idx = arr.findIndex(v => v > number);
arr.splice(idx > -1 ? idx : arr.length, 0, number);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Если в массиве не нашлось значения больше чем вставляемое (и `findIndex` вернул `-1`), помещаем новый элемент в конец массива (вместо `idx` в качестве индекса используя `array.length`, то есть индекс следующий за индексом самого последнего элемента).

---

Алгоритм можно улучшить, вместо поиска последовательным перебором применив [двоичный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) (например). Тема алгоритмов поиска в отсортированном массиве - за рамками предмета данного вопроса, но информации на эту тему в сети предостаточно.

**MDN:**
[Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const arr = [10, 15, 16, 19, 23, 25, 34]
const number = 21
    
arr.push(number)
arr.sort()
    
console.log(arr)
```